# Encode Camera preview ro raw h264 file

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, h.264, android-mediacodec

I want to write h264 frames to a file. I want to crop the preview frame also.MediaCodec can be used to encode camera frames. But I cant able to encode data.

Comment: Various examples of recording the camera preview as video can be found in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: I have seen Grafika example but I have less knowledge in opengl.Can u please tell me can how can I get crop the preview frame in Grafica.

Comment: Take a look at the "texture from camera" activity.  The "zoom" feature is essentially a source crop followed by a scale.

Comment: Surely I will do. Can u please tell me why am I getting greycale although I am converting yo YUV420Planner?

Comment: Hi @fadden I saw TextureFromCameraActivity. Icouldnot figure out how to get a square rect to record.Can u please upload a gist. Thanks

Comment: There are various questions on stackoverflow about taking square pictures; the general answer is you have to crop it.  To get decent video frame rates you'd need to do it the way the "texture from camera" activity does it, by selecting the source texture coordinates such that a square area is sampled.  I don't have any code samples that do this.

Comment: @fadden I can able to create a proper textureview.But the problem is how can I feed that texture to mediacodec?